# AJAX - Delay time between displaying AJAX results

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I have a search feature which uses an AJAX request to get data from my web-server.

I want to have a fade in animation which gets applied to each search result, with a slight delay so the last result fades in last (i.e. the first result loads, starts fading in, next one loads, starts fading in, etc.).

I have the code which loads the html into the search results area, but it *seems* like the results are displaying and running their "fade-in-animation" at the same time - although this could also be due to the fact that my computer is too slow.

Here's me code:

**JS**

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: '/PersonSearch',
  data: {
    'search_value': search
  },
  dataType: 'json',
})
.done(function(json) {
  $('#main').html('');
  $.each(json, function(key, value) {
    var search = $('<div />', {
       id: 'search' + key,
       'class': 'search-item off',
       html: 
        '<div class="basic-info">' +
          '<span class="first-name">' + value.First_name + '</span>' +
          '<span> </span>' +
          '<span class="last-name">' + value.Last_name + '</span>' +
        '</div>' +
        '<div class="dropdown">' +
          '<span class="phone-number">' + 'PHONE: ' + value.Phone_number + '</span>' +
          '<span class="email">' + 'EMAIL: ' + value.Email_address + '</span>' +
          '<div class="box edit"><img src="../media/gear.svg"/></div>' +
        '</div>'
    }).appendTo('#main');
    setTimeout(function() {
      search.removeClass('off');
    });
  });
});
```

**CSS**

```
.search-item.off{
  opacity: 0;
  top: 8px;
}
.search-item{
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  opacity: 1px;
  top: 0;
  transition: .75s;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="main">

</div>
```

Basically what the code does (so you do not need to piece it together yourself) is it adds the search result which has the class of `search-item off`, and once the `<div>` is loaded (using `setTimeout()`) it removes the `off` class, which then uses the `transition` CSS attrib to make it fade in over time.

I tried using `setTimeout()` on the `.appendTo('#main')` but that did not work.

**I need it so that there is a delay in posting each of the search results in the `#main` element so that there is a delay in running the fade in animation.**

Comment: Can you put this on fiddle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your idea could work, but you need to add a little delay to your call to `setTimeout`. The delay must be increased for each new result. To be sure that it is working, use a long delay at first (1000, ie. 1 second) then adjust with lover values as desired.

```
setTimeout(function() { ... }, 1000 * index);
```

Below is a simple snippet that illustrate the use of `setTimeout` to delay the successive calls to `append`

```js
$(function() {
  var $container = $('#container');
  $.each(['foo', 'bar', 'qux'], function(i, value) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      $container.append('<div>' + value + '</div>');
    }, 1000 * i);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="container">
</div>
```

Comment: thank you. This works, I just now need to fix some display issues (just from removing the class)

Answer (score 2):

try use

```
setTimeout(function() { ... }, 0);
```

It will wait that your content is fully loaded.

Answer (score 1):

This happens because `setTimeout` works asynchronously which means these `setTimeout` functions will start at 5ms, 10ms, 13ms, etc. and fire off at similar times as well. What you can do is define a `timeout` variable above ajax call and increase timeout at `each` call before `setTimeout` and give this `timeout` variable as the timeout value to the `setTimeout`. Following is an example (I know too much timeout):

```js
var timeout = 0;
$('div').each(function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  timeout += 1000;
  setTimeout(function() {
    $this.hide('slow');
  }, timeout);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>1</div>
<div>2</div>
<div>3</div>
<div>4</div>
<div>5</div>
```

Comment: wow, great code! I've decided to go with "`*`ing" the timeout (about answer) instead of "`=+`ing" it, but I will keep this in mind for the future

Answer (score 0):

Try using the timeout in the callback of the $.each() function.

`$.each(json, setTimeout(function(key, value) {...},1000) )`